# Is it legal for a company to make products specifically designed to fail immediately after the warranty expires?

Tags: is-x-legal, warranty, criminal-damage

Suppose that Bob's Electronics Company makes a smartphone with a one-year warranty. The phone's firmware has code which checks whether or not the warranty is current when booting, and if the warranty has expired, immediately bricks the phone. This is obviously unethical, but is it legal?